# How do I lock/freeze a CameraX preview TextureView?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm following the CameraX [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0) and also looked at their [sample app](https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt) and source code in Android Studio, but there doesn't seem to be a way to freeze or lock the `TextureView` that is showing the preview frames.

In the Camera2 API we can just call something like `cameraCaptureSession?.stopRepeating()` and the `TextureView` will stop getting input from the camera.

My use case for freezing the preview is to show the user the image that is currently being saved as I add other animations on top of the `TextureView`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
// You can unbind from any UseCase
CameraX.unbind(previewUseCase)
// In this way TextureView will hold the last frame


 // for version 1.0.0-alpha07
 cameraProvider.unbind(preview);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. And to reenable preview I simply bind the `previewUseCase` again.

Comment: @yevhen_69 I removed everything using `CameraX.unbindAll()` but it does hold the last frame. How to remove that also. Like a close camera something like?

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal If you want to also remove the last frame why not get rid of the Preview View altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PreviewView.getBitmap()` to capture the latest image that appears on the preview screen. It is very quick and you don't even have to rotate or flip the image.

**my XML code**:

```
        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/ivPreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

**my previous code**, processing the image from `OnImageCapturedCallback` or `OnImageSavedCallback` :

```
private fun showCapturedImage(bitmap: Bitmap, rotationDegrees: Float) {
        viewFinder.visibility = View.GONE
        ivPreview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        var rotatedBitmap = ImageUtils.rotateImage(bitmap, rotationDegrees).toSquare()
        if (isTakeFacePhoto){
            rotatedBitmap = rotatedBitmap.flipBitmap()
        }
        ivPreview.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap)
    }
```

**current code**, after using `PreviewView.getBitmap()` :

```
val bitmap = viewFinder.getBitmap()

showCapturedImage(bitmap)

private fun showCapturedImage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
           viewFinder.visibility = View.GONE
           ivPreview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
           ivPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

If you plan to save your image using `OnImageSavedCallback`, keep in mind that there might be a slight delay from `PreviewView.getBitmap()` and the saved file from `OnImageSavedCallback` so these two images can be really different depends on the delay.